# postfix failed to start

Tags: unix, postfix, shared-libraries

I try to set up `postfix` on my WS880 router under ASUSWRT-Merlin.
When I run it from command line, got error

> /opt/sbin/postlog: can't load library 'libresolv.so.0'

In fact `libresolv.so.0` lay in `/opt/lib`, and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/lib:/opt/lib'`
So `postfix` itself found this library. Even more - when I run `/opt/sbin/postlog` from command line, it start whitout problem.
But failed being called from `postfix`.

Here is informative part of `strace postfix`:

> fork()                                  = 11112
>   wait4(-1, /opt/sbin/postlog: can't load library 'libresolv.so.0'
>   [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 16}], 0, NULL) = 11112
>   --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) --- wait4(-1, 0xbefa3334, WNOHANG, NULL)    = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
>   exit(1)

Can somebody suggest a solution?

P.S. `ldd /opt/sbin/postlog` shows all libraries found, so I suspect the problem relates to kind of how `postfix` runs `postlog`...

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
postfix
```

or

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH postfix
```

or put your /opt/lib path into your /etc/ld.so.conf file

One of this options should work

Comment: Tried all the three. First two didn't help, third can't do because it's router - / is read only FS :(